# SQL concatenate one of the columns in groups of 10 with LISTAGG()

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, listagg

I need help writing a query that can concatenate one of the columns in groups of 10.

Example:

```
id1 | string1
id1 | string2
id1 | string3
...
id1 | string 1000
```

Since SQL do not allow too large concatenated strings I would like to maybe group 10 at a time so that I get:

```
id1 | string1,string2,...,string10
id1 | string11,string12,...,string20
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Oracle? (Add that tag.)

Comment: Please mention the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select      id,listagg (str,',') within group (order by str)

from       (select      id,str,row_number () over (partition by id order by str) - 1    as rn
            from        t
            ) 

group by    id,floor (rn / 10)
;
```

or if you don't care about the order -

```
select      id,listagg (str,',') within group (order by null)

from       (select      id,str,rownum - 1 as rn
            from        t
            ) 

group by    id,floor (rn / 10)
;
```

---

Sample

```
create table t
as
select          'id'    || to_char(ceil(level/100))     as id
                ,'str'  || lpad(to_char(level),4,'0')   as str
from            dual
connect by      level <= 1000
;
```

Comment: If you do ceil(rn/10) you don't need to bother with subtracting one from the rownum / row_number(), fwiw.

Comment: @Boneist, this is true, but since I'm working with multiple databases and some of them are using integer arithmetic I like to keep a similar logic.

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with switching (or not) to use `ceil` instead of `floor`?

Comment: @Boneist, what would be your GROUP BY expression when integer arithmetic is supported?

Comment: thanks, unfortunately i don't get the result I wanted. i tried your suggestion and got: id1 | string1,string1,string1... and id1 | string2,string2,string2

Comment: @user3438447, the code works. check yourself with the sample added at the bottom of my answer

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz what do you mean by "integer arithmetic"? `ceil` is the "opposite" of `floor` in that `floor` rounds the number down to the nearest whole number, and `ceil` rounds the number up to the nearest whole number. Thus, you would simply select the rownum or row_number() and then group by `ceil(rn/10)`. 1/10 -> 1, ...10/10 -> 1, 11/10 -> 2, etc. It's toMAYto, toMAHto, but it makes the query slightly less cluttered than using `floor`

Comment: @Boneist, In integer arithmetic (supported by Teradata, SQL Server, PosgreSQL, SQLLite etc.) 0/10 .. 9/10 = 0, 10/10 .. 19/10 = 1, 20/10 .. 29/10 = 2 etc. In those DB the GROUP BY expression would be (ROW_NUMBER-1)/10

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I'm pretty sure all those dbs also support CEIL (or it might be called CEILING) as well?

Comment: @Boneist, they are but you don't need to use FLOOR/CEIL since the division is already creating the step function.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz ah right, I get you now. Thanks for being patient with me *{:-)

Comment: @boniest - there was a discussion of Oracle and integer arithmetic on OTN not long ago. I should know, I was the one who started it - complaining about Oracle CLAIMING they do integer arithmetic with certain data types, when clearly they don't. Integer arithmetic, if supported and done right, should be much faster (when it is applicable) - something Oracle doesn't support even though most of it is written in C, which does.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Great stuff, I managed to get it to work. Thx!